# Debug mode in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

While I'm trying to run the tomcat server, it is going to debug mode instead of running the server. What is problem?
Checked all the preferences, everything is fine but couldn't find the actual problem where it is.

[image]

Comment: remove the breakpoints and than run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debugging java application deployed in tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677060/debugging-java-application-deployed-in-tomcat). There is a lot of explanation on how to use debug mode with eclipse and tomcat

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me to solve the isssue@Ashish Srivastava